# Can I pass back what system() return back into a variable? in C/Linux

Tags: c

So I have something like

```
system("(find . -type f | wc -l)");
```

How can I get the result of (find . -type f | wc -l) to store in a variable in C?

Comment: Redirect the output to a file and then read the file.

Comment: Use `popen()`, instead.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that. In that You can redirect the output to the one file. After using that file you can get the value from that.

```
 system("find . -type f | wc -l >output.txt");
```

Then open that file using the `open()` or `fopen()`. Get the output of that command. man page for [open](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) and [fopen.](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

Or else you can use `popen()`.

code using `popen()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int  main()                                
{

    FILE *pfp;
    int i;        

    if ((pfp = popen("find . -type f | wc -l", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("popen");
        return 10;
    }

    if (fscanf(pfp,"%d\n",&i) != 1)  
    {
        perror("fscanf");
        return 2;
    }

    printf("%d\n",i);
    pclose(pfp);

    return 0;
}
```

Code Using `fopen()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{ 

    FILE *fp;
    int i;

    if (system("find . -type f | wc -l >output.txt") != 0)
    {
        perror("system");
        return 10;
    }

    if ((fp = fopen("output.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        return 10;
    }

    if ( fscanf(pfp,"%d\n",&i) != 1 )  
    {
        perror("fscanf");
        return 2;
    }       
    printf("%d\n",i);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: or you can use `popen`.

Comment: `main` should return an `int`.

Comment: `fscanf(pfp, "%d", &i); printf("%d\n", i);` could be undefined behavior, check for `fscanf()`'s return value.

Comment: if you write the output to a file and then read it back you need a shell script instead of a c program...

Comment: How do I store the result into a file?

Comment: @facebook-10153638726717575 Using the redirection given in the system call!.

Comment: @facebook-10153638726717575 there is no point in doing that. If you want to use that technique use a shell script, otherwise use `popen()`.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S It doesn't mean we should.

Comment: @iharob Yes, I think that `popen` is the better way.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S also why to `exit(2)` in `main()` when you can just `return 2;` you should avoid `exit()` unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @iharob Ok I will change.

Comment: @iharob and Karthikeyan.R.S Thank you all very much for your answers. You litterally saved my day. This is a part of my assignment that I have been stuck on and thanks for your help I'm able to finish it. Thank you again.